# Выборка в sql с несколькими условиями

Tags: mysql

Всем привет.

Подскажите, как сделать выборку данных из таблицы с несколькими условиями. Сейчас у меня так:

```
SELECT NAME FROM b_iblock_element WHERE IBLOCK_ID=9 AND CREATED_BY=".$_REQUEST["userid"]
```

Мне надо добавить еще одно условие в запросе. Добавление еще одного AND в конце не помогло.
Как корректно написать, если надо проверить запись по 3, 4 или 5 полям?

Comment: напишите как писали, что не помогло

Comment: может тебе надо ИЛИ?

Comment: Нет. Надо сделать выборку с проверкой по 3 полям.

Comment: @frank как писал я написал в вопросе, попробовал добавить еще один AND (конкретно AND ACTIVE=Y). Но это не дало результат.

Comment: Пример по 3м полям почти аналогичен как по 2м. Если AND не сработало - значит не так написали. Нужно глянуть в чем ошибка

    SELECT `field` FROM `table` WHERE `field`='a' AND `field2`='b' AND `field3`='3'

полный пример в студию

Comment: SELECT NAME FROM b_iblock_element WHERE IBLOCK_ID=9 AND CREATED_BY=9 AND ACTIVE=Y

Вот так неработает, если же убрать последний AND то все в норме

Comment: Понял в чем причина, кавычки забыл.
SELECT NAME FROM b_iblock_element WHERE IBLOCK_ID=9 AND CREATED_BY=9 AND ACTIVE='Y'

Comment: @frank, не можете подсказать, если надо по 10, 11 или больше полям просто добавляют ANDы в конце или как то по другому делают?

Comment: @Saturn Вводя третье условие с помощью операции `AND` Вы ограничиваете выборку (она получается меньше или равной выборке по двум условиям). У Вас она сокращается до нуля. Может данные такие? Или Вам нужно другое обобщённое условие?

Comment: вообще в данном случаи надо бы было делать так:

$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(array("SORT"=>"ASC"),array("IBLOCK_ID"=>9,"CREATED_BY"=>$_REQUEST["userid"],"ACTIVE"=>"Y"));

while($ar_fields = $res->GetNext())
{
//  ... ваша работа с данными выборки
}

Причина - битрикс и его таблицы не постоянны для всех версий и если обновите его не факт что будет работать нужно пользоватся АПИ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отвечаю на 2 вопроса сразу. Кавычки обязательны, как в примере я написал

```
SELECT `field` FROM `table` WHERE `field`='a' AND `field2`='b' AND `field3`='3'
```

Писать также через AND. Дело в том, что новички привыкли без обязательных ковычек, т.к. в 99% случаев 'прокатит'. Вот возьмите за привычку писать как я написал. Я вот например когда пишу что то длинное складываю условия в массив, и уже в запросе им делаю implode.

Надеюсь максимально объяснил

Comment: А я условия, если их нисколько, беру в скобки. Это не обязательно?

Comment: скобки для другого нужны.

    SELECT `field` FROM `table` WHERE `field`='1' AND `field2`='2' AND (`field3`='3' OR `field3`='4') //если так, то 1е и 2е и (3е или 4е), т.е. 1е и 2е точно, 3е - одно из двух

    SELECT `field` FROM `table` WHERE `field`='1' AND `field2`='2' AND `field3`='3' OR `field3`='4' //если так, то 1е и 2е и 3е или 4е, т.е. тут одно из двух. 1: 1е и 2е и 3е, 2: 4е

Comment: @Saturn, да, я знаю, логику в школе проходил. Я просто когда только начинал учить mysql, у меня без скобок вокруг всех условий не заработало, с тех пор я всегда все условия в скобки беру...

Comment: Едрит, действительно полезная и правильная привычка, мне только что помогла. Как при SELECT так и при UPDATE.